# MarketingCloud crashing with CoreData failures

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk, mobilepush-ios

We're seeing MarketingCloud crashing on our app while trying to perform few CoreData tasks. Here are the 2 stack traces with errors that we see on Crashlytics:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0xa248 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x17a68 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreData                       0x164b0 +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]
3  CoreData                       0x1615c +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]
4  MarketingCloudSDK              0x4bf7c __hidden#3438_ + 161 (__hidden#3463_:161)
5  MarketingCloudSDK              0x58bdc __hidden#3606_ + 1011 (__hidden#3975_:1011)
6  MarketingCloudSDK              0x5eb74 __hidden#3678_ + 1674 (__hidden#3975_:1674)
7  MarketingCloudSDK              0x5e378 __hidden#3675_ + 1626 (__hidden#3975_:1626)
8  Foundation                     0x3b000 __NSThreadPerformPerform
9  CoreFoundation                 0xd622c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
10 CoreFoundation                 0xe2614 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
11 CoreFoundation                 0x6651c __CFRunLoopDoSources0
12 CoreFoundation                 0x7beb8 __CFRunLoopRun
13 CoreFoundation                 0x811e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
14 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal
15 UIKitCore                      0x3a2d88 -[UIApplication _run]
16 UIKitCore                      0x3a29ec UIApplicationMain
17 [app-name]                     0x25368 main + 24 (main.swift:24)
18 ???                            0x1ee22d948 (Missing)
```

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x9e88 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x178d8 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreData                       0x17a880 __43-[NSManagedObjectContext setParentContext:]_block_invoke
3  MarketingCloudSDK              0x832dc __hidden#4635_ + 63 (__hidden#4688_:63)
4  MarketingCloudSDK              0x5c768 __hidden#3662_ + 1395 (__hidden#3975_:1395)
5  MarketingCloudSDK              0x9cebc __hidden#4984_ + 608 (__hidden#5237_:608)
6  MarketingCloudSDK              0x999ec __hidden#4951_ + 109 (__hidden#5237_:109)
7  MarketingCloudSDK              0xa658 __hidden#754_ + 252 (__hidden#719_:252)
8  CoreFoundation                 0xa3a0 __NSARRAY_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
9  CoreFoundation                 0x910e0 -[__NSArrayI enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]
10 MarketingCloudSDK              0x9834 __hidden#307_ + 269 (__hidden#719_:269)
11 MarketingCloudSDK              0xae50 __hidden#750_ + 334 (__hidden#719_:334)
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout
13 libdispatch.dylib              0x1364c _dispatch_async_and_wait_invoke
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x3fdc _dispatch_client_callout
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x127f4 _dispatch_main_queue_drain
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x12444 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF
17 CoreFoundation                 0x9a6f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__
18 CoreFoundation                 0x7c058 __CFRunLoopRun
19 CoreFoundation                 0x80ed4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
20 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal
21 UIKitCore                      0x3a23d0 -[UIApplication _run]
22 UIKitCore                      0x3a2034 UIApplicationMain
23 [app-name]                     0x25368 main + 24 (main.swift:24)
24 ???                            0x1ebf0c960 (Missing)
```

We're using `MarketingCloudSDK-iOS` v.8.0.8 and `sfmc-sdk-ios` v.1.0.6 via SPM. The MarketingCloudSDK bundle is listed in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase. This bundle was copied from the v.8.0.8 of the SDK as this was the first one we integrated into our app.

Any other advice on how to prevent these issues?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please help us with the scenario where the crash is happening?
Is there any case where the SDK is re-initialized or does any of your usecase requires re-initialization of the SDK ?

Just in case, if you have added the below code from https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configuresdk.html:

```
// SDK: OPTIONAL IMPLEMENTATION (if using Data Protection)
func applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable(_ application: UIApplication) {
    if (SFMCSdk.mp.getStatus() != .operational) {
        self.configureSFMCSdk()
    }
}
```

It is optional as mentioned and needs to be used only if the data protection is enabled in the app.

Request you to please create a support ticket with crash logs, sdk state, debug logs by running the app in debug mode and mention @ppattabiraman@salesforce.com and @bmote@salesforce.com

Thanks,
Prakashini

Comment: Our application requires knowing the user location - retrieved from our back-end - to initialize MarketingCloud using the correct server, so the SDK is initialized only after the user logs in. This can also lead to re-initialization of the SDK if the a user tied to the server in Europe logs out and another user, located in the US, logs in within the same app session - which should be extremely rare.

Comment: Also, we do have data protection enabled, but adding `applicationProtectedDataDidBecomeAvailable(_:)`  didn't seem necessary as the SDK doesn't initialize on the app start up (as mentioned above).

Comment: I'm going to create a support ticket following your instructions. Thanks @prakashini-pattabiraman.