# MarketingCloudSDK Core Data Crash

Tags: marketing-cloud, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, ios, mobilepush-ios

I am experiencing crashes on an app in production with the following error message: 

*Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
+entityForName: nil is not a legal NSManagedObjectContext parameter searching for entity name 'SFMCEndpointConfigurationEntity*

And the Crashlytics State Traces as follows, (and similar to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/393730/marketingcloud-crashing-with-coredata-failures)):

```
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0xed5e0 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x2bc00 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreData                       0x3188 +[NSEntityDescription entityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]
3  CoreData                       0x10d498 +[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:inManagedObjectContext:]
4  MarketingCloudSDK              0x4ef58 (Missing UUID d16d89add9393413ba7302df3b40c2bc)
5  MarketingCloudSDK              0x5bc00 (Missing UUID d16d89add9393413ba7302df3b40c2bc)
6  MarketingCloudSDK              0x61b6c (Missing UUID d16d89add9393413ba7302df3b40c2bc)
7  MarketingCloudSDK              0x61378 (Missing UUID d16d89add9393413ba7302df3b40c2bc)
8  Foundation                     0xf6064 __NSThreadPerformPerform
9  CoreFoundation                 0x37acc __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
10 CoreFoundation                 0x36d48 __CFRunLoopDoSource0
11 CoreFoundation                 0x354fc __CFRunLoopDoSources0
12 CoreFoundation                 0x34238 __CFRunLoopRun
13 CoreFoundation                 0x33e18 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
14 GraphicsServices               0x35ec GSEventRunModal
15 UIKitCore                      0x22f2fc -[UIApplication _run]
16 UIKitCore                      0x22e938 UIApplicationMain
17 Itaucard                       0xb95c main + 12 (main.swift:12)
18 ???                            0x1d224bd44 (Missing)
```

I'm using `MarketingCloudSDK-iOS v.8.0.9` and `sfmc-sdk-ios v.1.0.6`, and the app crashes mostly on `iOS 16 and 17`. 
It has been deployed initially via Cocoapods, and now by installing it manually according to [this documentation](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-addsdk.html).
But both attempts result in the same error message.

I’ve tried to add the following line: SFMCSdk.setKeychainAccessErrorsAreFatal(errorsAreFatal: false)
Which didn’t prevent the crash from happening

The app does not have the data protection capability enable, so the optional implementation from [this documentation](https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/get-started/get-started-configuresdk.html) did not work either.

I’ve also the setLogger initialized with a .debug and running only on a Debug mode like follows:

```
        #if DEBUG
        SFMCSdk.setLogger(logLevel: .debug)
        #endif
```

To be able to provide you the result of SFMCSdk.state()   of the crash (in order to create a support ticket), would it be ok to run the setLogger in production? Would it be any advantages of initializing the setLogger with a .error instead of a .debug?

Any other orientation in order to solve this problem?
Thank you!